# How to use a VLOOKUP as a criteria in SUMIF?

Tags: excel, vlookup

First allow me to provide some background:

I have two tables, the first with one column that has a key value, which is just one letter of the alphabet and a second column with values that later I want to sum. The second table also has two columns. The first contains a list of the distinct values from the key column of the first table, and the second contains a binary value of 1 or 0. Examples below:

```
Table 1:                 Table 2:
A   50                   A   1
A   50                   B   0
B   100                  C   0
C   125
```

The binary values in Table 2 are variable based on other information contained in my workbook. Now what I want to do is to sum all of the values in Table 1, where the Primary key is "turned on" in Table 2, aka the value in the second column is 1. I've tried multiple iterations of using SUMIF and VLOOKUP and LOOKUP as the criteria but can't get anything to work. Can anyone help out with a way, either using VBA or in the cell formula itself, to get this done?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure it can be done as you say - however, I'm sure somebody will come prove me wrong :)   In the meantime, have you tried a "helper" column ?  That is, add a third column to "Table 1" with your vlookup, pulling the binary bit over. Then you just do the SUMIF using that column ;)

Answer (score 0):

How's this? Place this next to the `1` or `0` in your Table2, `=IF(F1>0,SUMIFS($B$1:$B$4,$A$1:$A$4,E1),"")`:

[image]

and if you drag that down, it'll return blanks for the "letter" that doesn't have duplicates.

Edit: Or, per @pnuts, this `=SUMIF(A:A,"="&INDEX(E:E,MATCH(1,F:F,0)),B:B)`

Comment: @pnuts - Good call, I can't really tell completely from the OP what he needs, but I think the combination of my answer and your comment should get him there.